# How to send message to short codes in android?

Tags: android, smsmanager

I have just started learning Android. My work requires me to send sms from android app to a shortcode number.
I can send sms to a normal number just fine. But when it comes to the short code the sms is not sent.
Here is my working code for sending sms:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("01700121212", null, "hello", null, null);
```

But when I try send a message to a short code number like "21213" using this piece of code

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage("21213", null, "hello", null, null);
```

the sms is not sent.

```
    I've checked the 'Android Monitor' and I do not receive any error. I've also checked http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html but it was not of much help regarding this short code.
```

**Edit:** Problem resolved. Looks like there was some weird issue with my testing device. It could not even send message from my Message App

Answer (score 0):

Add uses-permission in your project manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Comment: The permission was always there. In my post I have mentioned that I was able to send message to numbers like '01700121212'. The problem occurs when I try to send message to numbers like '21213'

Comment: 1. Press the Menu key from the home screen.

2. Select Settings.

3. Select the More tab at the top right corner of your screen.

4. Select Application Manager.

5.Slide the screen to the All section.

6. Select Messages.

7. Under the Permissions section you will find a drop down menu with 3 options for Sending Premium SMS (this isn't very obvious but is in the middle of the permissions text)
    Ask - Never Allow - Always Allow
8. Select the desired option (Ask is the default)

Comment: This is the answer of another question, not mine. Thanks for trying to help anyway